# Issue fine-tuning a simple embedding network

Tags: machine-learning, neural-networks

I'm trying to learn an embedding on Cifar-10 by finetuning ResNet-50 with a few added layers:

```
cifar10 = ResourceData["CIFAR-10"]
toRule[{img1_ -> l1_, img2_ -> l2_}] := {img1, img2} -> l1 != l2;
trainingData = Table[toRule@RandomSample[cifar10, 2], 30000];

res = NetModel["ResNet-50 Trained on ImageNet Competition Data"]
f = NetTake[res, {1, "flatten_0"}];
net = NetChain[{f, 50, DropoutLayer[0.3], Ramp, 2}]
neo = NetPairEmbeddingOperator[net]

trained = NetTrain[neo, trainingData, 
                LearningRateMultipliers -> {-4 -> 1, -1 -> 1, _ -> 0.01}]
embedding = NetExtract[trained, "Net"]

groups = KeySort@GroupBy[RandomSample[cifar10, 1000], Last -> First];
points = Map[embedding, groups];
ListPlot[KeyValueMap[Legended[#2, #1] &, points], Frame -> True, 
 Axes -> False, AspectRatio -> 1, FrameTicks -> False, 
 PlotStyle -> PointSize[0.012]]
```

However, the loss looks really weird (it should not be 0 when the training starts):

[image]

And so does the embedding:

[image]

This should be a simple task, what am I doing wrong here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ah, simple mistake, since the net is inside an operator, it should be:

```
LearningRateMultipliers -> {{"Net", -4;;-1;;2 -> 1}, {"Net", _ -> 0.01}}
```

I'll forgive myself since there is no example of using `LearningRateMultipliers` inside a `NetPairEmbeddingOperator` in the documentation (perhaps that would be nice to add).